# Setting session variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, session-variables

I am getting name and email id of a user after he logs in via facebook to my website..
I want to add those variables in session on login form itself using javascript; 
I tried following:

```
FB.api('/me', function(me) {
        if (me.name) {
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name; <% Session["fbName"] = me.name; %>
        }
}
```

it gives error like me (in this line: <%Session["fbName"] = me.name; %>) does not exist in the current context etc.. my div "auth-displayname" is getting that value but I'm having problem with session variable

How can I do this

Answer (score 58):

You can use

`sessionStorage.SessionName = "SessionData"` ,

`sessionStorage.getItem("SessionName")` and

`sessionStorage.setItem("SessionName","SessionData");`

**See the supported browsers on http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage**

Answer (score 10):

A session is stored **server side**, you can't modify it with JavaScript. Sessions may contain sensitive data.

You can modify **cookies** using `document.cookie`.

You can easily find many examples how to modify cookies.

Comment: Many languages keep session variables on the client side, via cookies.

Comment: @bernando for example?

Comment: @BernardoSiu typically the client only sees a session identifier cookie, and even that can be hidden from JavaScript with _HttpOnly cookies_. It's important to realize the difference between sessions and cookies, they're not the same thing.

Comment: Here's some info on the session API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 5):

It is very important to understand both `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` as they both have different uses:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage):

> All of your web storage data is contained within two object-like structures inside the browser: sessionStorage and localStorage. The first one persists
>   data for as long as the browser is open (the data is lost when the browser is
>   closed) and the second one persists data even after the browser is
>   closed and then opened again.

**`sessionStorage`** - Saves data until the browser is closed, the data is deleted when the tab/browser is closed.

**`localStorage`** - Saves data "forever" even after the browser is closed **BUT** you shouldn't count on the data you store to be there later, the data might get deleted by the browser at any time because of pretty much anything, or deleted by the user, best practice would be to validate that the data is there first, and continue the rest if it is there. (or set it up again if its not there)

To understand more, read here: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) | [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)