# How to recognize from what page the user has landed on another page?

Tags: javascript

```
Page A
Page B
Page C
```

If the user is coming from `page A` do something on `page C` (within the same website)
If the user is coming from `page B` do something else on `page C` (within the same website)

What would be the best approach to do that in JS? (dont use `document.referrer`)

Comment: How are you defining "best"?

Comment: The "don't use document.referrer" makes me think this is a homework assignment... What have you tried?

Comment: Note: there are at least 5 different ways of doing it I can think of. You need to narrow it down.

Comment: To me the best means cross browser solution (I support IE8++, KIT browsers - iOS, Android)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two decent solutions:

1. When Page A loads Page C, include a variable in the URL that essentially says "*loaded from page A*". (Same applies to Page B.)
2. When Page A is loaded, set either a cookie, `localStorage`, or `sessionStorage` variable that says "*loaded from page A*". (Same applies for Page B.) Then when Page C is loaded, check the variable to see if either Page A or Page B was the most recently opened page. (You may also want to set a timeout/expiration-time on the cookie, localStorage, or sessionStorage.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a global variable that will hold the location. When you load a page. assign that variable the location

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
document.URL;
```

Another option would be using cookies.

Comment: A "global variable" in the Javascript sense (i.e. stored in `window`) would be lost when switching from one page to another.

Comment: It is not stored in windows, you get the current url from windows. The javascript variable remains constant and therefore accessible from multiple pages on the site.

Comment: Try it. You'll see it isn't. As long as we are talking about a regular Javascript variable, i.e. not cookies, local storage, session storage, etc, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesnt make a lot of sense (to me), especially because you havent included any framework/stack you're using (which this responsibility would likely fall on).

That said, I would use a variable with session getters and setters.  You can parse the query string or URL, set that equal to a session variable, then get that session variable when you're ready to use it.

Here's [how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076013/setting-session-variable-using-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top) session getters and setters in javascript

Comment: Let say that I am not using any framework... I am looking for a clean js solution. I want to do sessionStorage with a fallback to cookies for old browsers but wanted to make sure if that is the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can have `page A` and `page B` set a cookie that indicates which page they are. Then `page C` can check the cookie value.