# Remove session's previous set value

Tags: html, jsp

I have a page and there are 3 images in that so now when 
click an image  want to set session attribute like this

```
<a href="voting.jsp"><img onclick="myfunction('image_one')" src="image_one.jpg"></a>
<a href="voting.jsp"><img onclick="myfunction('image_two')" src="image_two.jpg"></a>
<a href="voting.jsp"><img onclick="myfunction('image_three')" src="image_three.jpg"></a>
<script>
function myfunction(name)
    if(name='image_one')
        <% session.setAttribute("user","image_one") %>
    else if(name='image_two')
        <% session.setAttribute("user","image_two")%>
    elseif(name='image_three')
        <% session.setAttribute("user","image_three")%>
</script>
```

now the answer is alway image_three when i use session.getAttribute in the voting.jsp  page
why

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use server side code(scriptlet) in javascript/JQuery function. Scriptlet code executes at server side and Web-Container(Tomcat Server) sends clean HTML page as a response.

So basically you are doing all wrong stuff here. You can't set session in JavaScript function.

You can work in this flow :
1.Set value of any variable accordingly image is selected.

2.Send this value to servlet by submitting page and set session by accordingly value you get.

[Setting session variable using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076013/setting-session-variable-using-javascript). Check this.

Answer (score 0):

Before set value to session remove session value.

```
<%  session.removeAttribute("user");
    session.setAttribute("user","image_one"); %>
```